# Handsontable breaking build on Angular 14

Tags: angular, handsontable

I'm currently testing out the use of Handsontable for a project I'm working on.

I got it working fine within Angular 11 and have recently upgraded to Angular 14 which the HotTableModule is causing problems on.

The build works until it goes to load the webpage which is just a white screen with the following errors in the console:

["Uncaught TypeError: **webpack_require**.h is not a function"
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'MIXIN_NAME')"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tar9T.png)

Comment: I think it’s only available for angular 12, they still have to upgrade their code to ng14

Comment: I've just used the latest Angular CLI (14.0.5) to create a project and installed the latest Handsontable v12.1.1 and it runs the build and shows the table. Could you share your webpack config?

Comment: @ABudnik I'm not entirely sure what info you're after because webpack is mentioned in quite a few places, mostly in the package-lock.json: 
        "webpack": "5.72.1",
        "webpack-dev-middleware": "5.3.1",
        "webpack-dev-server": "4.9.0",
        "webpack-merge": "5.8.0",
        "webpack-subresource-integrity": "5.1.0"

Also mentioned in package.json and polyfills.ts.

Comment: This looks like a problem with your config, but it is hard to say what kind of problem. We have examples with Angular versions 9-14 that work OK: https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/tree/develop/examples/next/docs. They use Webpack 4 and 5.

Maybe comparing these examples with your setup can help. 

Maybe we could help better more directly at support@handsontable.com